# Make a string titleCase

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I make a string Title Case Like This?
Other dart solutions did not work for me as some of the functions are not to be found in flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will do the work:

```
extension CapTitleExtension on String {
  String get titleCapitalizeString => this.split(" ").map((str) => str[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1)).join(" ");
}
```

now use this with importing all Extension in any file.

```
import CapTitleExtension
            
final helloWorld = 'hello world'.titleCapitalizeString; // 'Hello World'
```

with function without Extension

```
String titleCase(String? text) {
  if (text == null) throw ArgumentError("string: $text");

  if (text.isEmpty) return text;

  return text
      .split(' ')
      .map((word) => word[0].toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
      .join(' ');
}
```

Comment: A better name might be `titleCapitalizeString`.

Comment: @Chris yeah agree in this case, `titleCapitalizeString` is a better name.

Comment: what's ``str.capitalize``  ??

Comment: @AaravPrasad try the update code for your case.

Comment: @OMiShah that was the extension i was using but i forgot to add that extention code, so i just update the code here.